# Number of days for each project together with start date and end date for each project

Tags: sql, oracle

It does not meter if you offer me a solution in Oracle or SQL Server or MySQL or PostgreSQL.

All I need is a different approach, another way of thinking. Thank you
The start date and end date of each project are required along with the number of days - how long each project lasted.
Projects do not overlap.
I tried to solve it using lag and lead but I didn't succeed.
Usually I look for several solutions to a problem but unfortunately I only found one solution to this problem on google.
I'm interested in other approaches if that's the only way I'm learning.
This is the solution I found on google

```
WITH STARTDATES AS (
SELECT startdate
FROM project
WHERE startdate NOT IN (SELECT enddate FROM project) ),
-- get end dates not present in start date column (these are “true” project end dates) 
ENDDATES AS (
SELECT enddate
FROM project
WHERE enddate NOT IN (SELECT startdate FROM project) ),
-- filter to plausible start-end pairs (start < end), then find correct end date for each start date (the minimum end date, since there are no overlapping projects)
t3 AS (
SELECT startdate, min(enddate) AS enddate
FROM STARTDATES, ENDDATES
WHERE startdate < enddate
GROUP BY startdate )
SELECT startdate, enddate, enddate - startdate AS project_duration
FROM t3 
ORDER BY 3,1;
```

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: What dbms did you use? mysql<>sql-server

Comment: Hello i use oracle but it does not meter if you can offer me a solution in a different database.Thank you

Comment: Please add sample data as text.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Dale K ok i will do that.thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `LAG` window function get the next row of `STARTDATE` then compare subtract `ENDDATE`

then use condition aggregate function get `grp` make grouping.

```
SELECT MIN(STARTDATE) STARTDATE,
       MAX(ENDDATE) ENDDATE,
       COUNT(*) DURATION
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,SUM(CASE WHEN t1.daydiff = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY STARTDATE)  grp
    FROM (
        SELECT T.*,LAG(ENDDATE) OVER(ORDER BY STARTDATE) - STARTDATE daydiff
        FROM T
    ) t1
) t1
GROUP BY grp;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1937da68b294cc7bf2ae00c842bd801b)

Comment: Ok.i will tast your solution right now.Many thanks

Comment: @Florin I edit my answer thanks.

Comment: i test the last solution,is working perfect in oracle..many many thanks.i will vote your answer.very fast answer.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

select min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date, count(*) as Project_Duration

from
(select *,sum(case when t1.date_diff =0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER ( ORDER BY start_date) as days

from
(select *, lag(end_date) over ( order by end_date)-start_date as date_diff from dataset) as t1) as t2
group by days;

Comment: Nitin Arora you provide the same answer like D-Shih.